# Is there any way for aria-live="assertive" without role="alert" on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, firefox, accessibility

Is there any tricks to get aria-live working without role="alert" in firefox on windows? (using JAWS). It seems to only work with role="alert" which announces "Alert" before each message in the live area which is unfortunately ruining my browser game experience on firefox.

Thanks anyone who tries

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#controls").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    $("#alert-div").empty().append(" ");
    var text = $(this).attr("data-test");
      window.setTimeout(function(){
       $("#alert-div").empty().append(text); 
      }, 500);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert-div" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
</div>

<div id="controls">
  <a href="javascript:;" data-test="Say this message">A</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" data-test="A different message">B</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried starting out simple and just have `aria-live=polite` and leave off the `role` and `aria-atomic`?  We use `aria-live` all the time with great success.

Comment: @slugolicious You're right! Thank you

Comment: I'm going to move my comment to the answer section so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried starting out simple and just have `aria-live=polite` and leave off the `role` and `aria-atomic`? We use `aria-live` all the time with great success.